# Как сделать настройку изменяемого текста

Tags: android, android-textview

У меня есть разные `activity` и `fragment` и в них есть `TextView` как мне сделать так чтобы в настройке я мог выбрав допустим нажав на `RadioButton` и размер текста менялся на другой. Типа как настройка (Размер шрифта). Можно какой-то пример или объяснить как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вам нужно эти настройки где-то хранить. Это может быть `SharedPreference` если настройки долгосрочные (т.е. актуальные после того как приложение закроется), либо же какой-то `Singleton` который живет в течении приложение если эти настройки актуальны в пределах одной сессии.

При старте каждого экрана вы можете получать актуальные настройки из вашего хранилища и в зависимости от настроек проставлять нужные вам размеры шрифта.

Если таких элементов много, то стоит подумать о том как это централизовать. Возможно создать какой-то класс в котором будет инкапсулирована это логика. К примеру он может на вход получать список `View` которые нужно настроить и внутри в зависимости от настроек проставлять им нужные значение.